# Entity Framework lazy loading does not work (foreign key object null)

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-core

```
public class Game
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public virtual Team HomeTeam { get; set; }
    public virtual Team AwayTeam { get; set; }
    public virtual Lineup HomeLineup { get; set; } 
    public virtual Lineup AwayLineup { get; set; }
    public int Spectators { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Goal> Goals { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return base.ToString();
    }
}
```

I am trying to query this games table, the foreign keys of the virtual declared attributes gets inserted correctly, but when I try to query the games table, every foreign key object is null, so lazy loading does not seem to work.

HOWEVER on the first start of the application, when I am inserting new data into the database, it does work. When I restart the app the foreign key object are all null, primitive data types are still working.

I am querying like this:

```
try
{
    var context = services.GetRequiredService<ManagerContext>();
    DbInitializer.Initialize(context, logger);
    List<Game> games = context.Games.ToList<Game>();

    if(games[0] != null)
    {
       GameSimulation.SimulateGame(games[0], logger);
    }
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    logger.LogError(ex, "Fehler beim Erstellen von Testdaten!");
}
```

Comment: What version of EF?

Comment: It is a ASP.NET Core Web API, so i assume it is EF Core

Comment: Lazy Loading in EF Core doesn't happen automatically.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data#lazy-loading  And asp.net core 2.x can run on .NET Framework.  And EF 6.3 is supported on .NET Core.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Problem is that `.UseLazyLoadingProxies()` is not defined for `DbContextOptionsBuilder` in my case. And in references i have the EntityFramework packages version 3.1.2?

Comment: That extension method is defined in the package `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Proxies`.

Comment: ok there seems to be something wrong in my setup. There is no `Proxies` in `Microsoft.EntityFrameowkCore` for me

Comment: It's an additional NuGet package.https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Proxies/

Comment: Thanks, got it now! Besides that, is it recommendet to use LazyLoading for APIs?

Comment: No.  Use Explicit Loading or Eager Loading for APIs.  Otherwise your JavaScript serializer can end up in loops or traversing your whole entity model.